# Is it possible to pass a gesture from the current view controller to popover viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

In my presented `ViewController` i have a button where on the long press I present a `ViewController` with `modalPresentationStyle` `popover`. The thing is I would like to pass the same touch gesture to the popover so that I don't have to make another touch event to make things work. Is it possible in my current situation or do u suggest work around?

```
interactionViewController?.delegate = self
interactionViewController?.indexpathRow = indexPathRow

interactionViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
interactionViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = .clear
interactionViewController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 220)
interactionViewController?.view.layer.cornerRadius = 25

let popoverMenuViewController = interactionViewController?.popoverPresentationController
popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
popoverMenuViewController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = PopupControllerBackgroundView.self
popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0,y:0,width: 1,height: 1)
popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self

self.present(self.interactionViewController!, animated: false, completion: { [weak self] in

    self?.interactionViewController?.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    self?.interactionViewController?.view.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
})
```

Comment: did you try to pass? What did you write? A simple option remove gesture from one view & assign to another view without allocation.

Comment: i haven't passed it yet rather i should say it's a bit confusing on my part how it should work. Like when i am making a touch to my button it opens the popover view controller but to play with the popover components i need to make another touch to my popover as dragging my finger with the same touch event is not working.